# Lync Pool discovery issue in SCOM 2007 R2

Tags: monitoring, lync, scom, instant-messaging

Trying to get my Lync topology to show up in the SCOM 2007 R2 console.

So far, I've done the following:

1. Deployed the SCOM agent to the Lync servers
2. Enabled Agent Proxy on all Front End servers in the primary pool
3. Imported the Lync Management Pack in SCOM

Unfortunately, the Pools/Servers/other lists in SCOM show up as blank. In the Discovery State View, I see 3 of my 4 FEs as Healthy, 1 of the healthy having the healthy LS Discovery Script checkmark.

The 1 FE with the critical state in the Discovery State view has a permission issue when running the picker script - shouldn't affect topology discovery, right?

On the SCOM server itself, I see a bunch of Event ID 1102 (where servername.com is the name of my server, I replaced it for confidentiality sake here):

> Rule/Monitor "Microsoft.SystemCenter.HealthService.Diagnostic.ICMPPingDiagnostic" running for instance "servername.com" with id:"{CC1A2902-5C33-92C1-80EB-5D09C5162397}" cannot be initialized and will not be loaded. Management group "SCOM_NY_DEV"

Additionally, on the server to be monitored, I see some Event ID 10:

> AD ClientPerspective Discovery : Active Directory Helper Objects Installation unsuccessful. MSI was not found at the specified location

as well as some 5001:

> AD ClientPerspective Discovery : Active Directory Helper Objects Installation unsuccessful. MSI was not found at the specified location

After a great deal of searching, I see that there might be a number of issues. Firstly, if I somehow forcibly install oomads.msi to the server(s) with the agents, will that clear up my issues?

Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the primary issue here was the SCOM 64 bit oomads.msi was missing from the helperobject directory inside the default SCOM installation path.

I copied it over from the SCOM manager and restarted the healthservice on the affected agent nodes. Reloaded the management pack on the manager to force the rediscovery, I seem to be in business.

Hopefully, someone will solve their issue finding this in the future :)